# arlpy.bf.steering doesn't exist in ARL py tools package

Tags: python, signal-processing, acoustics

I am trying to run this example from ARL py Tools [documentation](https://arlpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bf.html) for generating
Barlett Beampattern which mentions usage of `arlpy.bf.steering()`; but when I try to run it says `steering()` not found.

```py
sd = arlpy.bf.steering(np.linspace(0, 5, 11), 1500, np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 181))
bp = arlpy.bf.bartlett_beampattern(90, 1500, sd, show=True)
```

Error:

```sh
AttributeError: module 'arlpy.bf' has no attribute 'steering'
```

The documentation notes from April 2020 also mention the usage for the same function but doesn't show definition of that function anywhere.

Refer: Page 16 at https://arlpy.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/
The version of `arlpy` I am using is **1.7.0** which appears to be the latest.

Please advise what should be done to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved now, as it seems that it `arlpy.bf.steering()` stayed from the pervious version which is now outdated and it will be updated to `arlpy.bf.steering_plane_wave()` in the next release.

Check my issue post on their github for more information: https://github.com/org-arl/arlpy/issues/61 which has been closed now.